# Do action after three seconds JS

Tags: javascript

What I want to do here is to let me to attack monster every three seconds. Heres my code:

```
                user.last_attack_time = Date.now();
                user.save();


            let nextAttack = user.last_attack_time+3000;

            if(user.last_attack_time <= nextAttack) {
```

The if statement still works if I attack faster than one second. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: You might want to use `setInterval()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: But is setInterval are made for not automized things ? Here user is clicking the button for every attack

Comment: a <= a + 3000 will always be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `if(Date.now() >= nextAttack)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
let x = a_function_returning_a_number();
let y = x + 3000;
if (y < x) { ... }
```

you really do expect the code inside braces to be executed?

What you should do is:

```
let t = Date.now();
if (t > this.last_attack+3000) {
    // Valid attack
    this.last_attack = t;
    ...
}
```